# How can I configure IBM ACE running in my local machine to use IBM MQ running in docker container?

Tags: docker, ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus

I just need some help in connecting to MQ running in docker(ibmcom/mq) from ACE running on my local machine. I have tried many ways in putting a message in queue through App connect flow but no luck so far. I have access to MQ web console at port 9443 and listener port at 1414. I am using my personal MacBook to try this out. Appreciate any help I get on this. thanks.

In ACE messageflow, I have configured MQ output node with QM name, server, listener port, channel name and security identity. MQ in docker comes equipped with the app channel, "DEV.APP.SVRCONN" , queue manager, "QM1" and queue "DEV.QUEUE.1"
The error logs from MQ docker container at path /mnt/mqm/data/errors, *AMQERR01.LOG, AMQ6184W: An internal IBM MQ error has occurred on queue manager QM1.*
I have attached here the MQ output node properties screen grab. I have used security identity by running mqsisetdbparms command using username and password that I use to log into mq web console, the default one that comes with docker mq. username- admin; password - passw0rd.

The error I see in QMGRs error folder is, ie at  mnt/mqm/data/qmgrs/QM1/errors/AMQERR01.JSON

```
"message":"AMQ9207E: The data received from host '172.17.0.1' on channel '????' is not valid."
"message":"AMQ9492E: The TCP/IP responder program encountered an error."}
```

I have also tried removing the username/password from ACE but no luck. Also tried using username as 'mqm' and password as 'passw0rd' but again no help.

Comment: What errors are you seeing the MQ AMQERR01.LOG on your local machine? What errors is IBM ACE showing you?

Comment: This question is way too general, you will need to add specifics of how you configured the mq output node. But in general, you need a listener and a channel configured on your QM, and also set up (or disable) authentication and authorization, and than you need to configure the mq output node in your flow accordingly.

Comment: Where is App Connect running?

Comment: @MoragHughson Hi, I am seeing this in AMQERR01.LOG, AMQ6184W: An internal IBM MQ error has occurred on queue manager QM1. 
In ACE ExceptionList, I see the same error, 
Severity:INTEGER:3
Number:INTEGER:2677
Text:CHARACTER:Failed to connect to queue manager

Comment: @AttilaRepasi Hi, I think I have done in a similar fashion. Configured MQ output node with QM name, server, listener port, channel name and security identity. MQ in docker comes equipped with the app channel, DEV.APP.SVRCONN. Let me know if any additional details are required. thanks.

Comment: @chughts I am running developer edition ACE on my laptop, not a docker container .

Comment: Hi - did you look in `MQ_DATA_PATH/errors/AMQERR01.LOG` on your local machine - i.e. where the client is? Please edit your question with what you saw rather than replying in a comment, makes it much easier for us to read.

Comment: @MoragHughson Thanks for suggestion and sorry I made a mess with this question post. I have edited the original post with more details. Please check.

Comment: Hi, again, one more time - can you you look in the `MQ_DATA_PATH/errors/AMQERR01.LOG` on your local machine, i.e. where ACE is running, and show us what is in there, not the error log for your queue manager. I'm looking for client connection error messages.

Comment: P.S. The user id and password that you use to log onto the mq web console will not work for a client connection into the queue manager. You will need the credentials to connect to the queue manager.

Comment: Given the liklihood that this is now a credential checking problem, it is worth looking at your queue manager in docker error log too. Please look in `mnt/mqm/data/qmgrs/QM1/errors/AMQERR01.LOG` and not the one you looked in before.

Comment: @MoragHughson Hi. Sorry, I could not find a location in my terminal for this, MQ_DATA_PATH/errors/AMQERR01.LOG. Also I have edited the original post with more details on mgr error logs.

Comment: Looks like you found it just fine as I see you have updated your question with the details. FY: MQ_DATA_PATH is an environment variable that shows the data path for MQ, which various for different people's install preferences or platform.

Comment: You show an error, "Invalid data". There should be an FDC written for this. Look in `mnt/mqm/data/errors` for a file `AMQ*.FDC` with the same timestamp as the error message, and add the bad data shown in there to your question.